# hide row if one of the columns is empty

Tags: jquery, hide, row

I have a table with a couple of rows each row with two columns, first left column is the title or topic and the right column is their value. If the right column is empty i need to hide the corresponding row, the whole row itself with the title . How to do it in jquery?

```
<table cellpadding="10" class ="EventDetail">
    <tr>
        <td class="TableFields">Who Should Enroll?:</td>
        <td>Everyone 18 and older who would like to attend</td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td class="TableFields">Handicapped Access:</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="TableFields">Parking Notes:</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="TableFields">Instructor:</td>
        <td>John Filler</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.EventDetail tr').filter(function(){
   return $(this).find('td:eq(1):empty').length > 0;
}).hide();
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaSuX/5/)**

Alternative solution

```
$('.EventDetail tr').find('td:eq(1):empty').parent().hide();
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaSuX/6/)**